# GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController to show predefined places if no input text in the search bar

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

Is there a way to show in the GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController custom predefined results like home/work address, favorites or recent places?

I have the places saved in UserDefaults just don't know how to show them when clicking on the search bar, before any text input is introduced.

I manage to do this using MapKit and custom table view:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    print("----UPDATE SEARCH RESULTS")

    guard let mapView = mapView,
        let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text
    else {
        return
    }
    matchingItems = []

    if(searchBarText == " "){
        print("Text: SPACE")
        if let location = currentLocation{
            matchingItems = [location]
        }
        if(home != nil){
            addressToPlacemark(searchParam: home!, region: nil, reload: false)
        }

        if(work != nil){
            addressToPlacemark(searchParam: work!, region: nil, reload: false)
        }
    } else if(searchBarText.characters.count >= 3){
        addressToPlacemark(searchParam: searchBarText, region: mapView.region, reload: true)
    } else{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func addressToPlacemark(searchParam: String, region: MKCoordinateRegion?, reload: Bool) {
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchParam
    if let region = region{
         request.region = region
    }

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start { (response, error) in

        print("ERROR: \(String(describing: error))")
        guard let response = response else {
            print("NO VALID RESPONSE")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        }

        self.matchingItems.append(contentsOf: response.mapItems.map({ (item:MKMapItem) -> MKPlacemark in
            item.placemark
        }))

        var uniqueItems:[MKPlacemark] = []

        for item in self.matchingItems{
            let first = uniqueItems.first(where: { (uniqueItem:MKPlacemark) -> Bool in
                uniqueItem.title == item.title && uniqueItem.coordinate.latitude == item.coordinate.latitude && uniqueItem.coordinate.longitude == item.coordinate.longitude
            })
            if(first == nil){
                uniqueItems.append(item)
            }
        }
        self.matchingItems = uniqueItems
        if(reload || self.matchingItems.count == self.savedAddressesCount){
            print("Reloaded data")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I've "tricked" the UISearchController to show the table view by programmatically adding a space when clicked:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("searchBarTextDidBeginEditing - CLICK")
    searchBar.text = " "
}


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if(searchText.characters.count > 1 && searchText.hasPrefix(" ")){
        searchBar.text = searchText.substring(from: searchText.index(searchText.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
        print("searchBarTextDidChange - TRIM")
    }else if(searchText.isEmpty){
        searchBar.text = " "
        print("searchBarTextDidChange - EMPTY")
    }
}
```

Can I do something similar using Google Maps? Is this even possible just by using GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController or should I use a custom ResultsViewController?